# Find out what disk drives are installed Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server

I've install Ubuntu on new server with 2HDD. When i run `lsblk`, i see this result :

```
sda       8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0     4G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0     4G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sda2    8:2    0   512M  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sda3    8:3    0     4G  0 part  
│ └─md2   9:2    0     4G  0 raid1 /tmp
├─sda4    8:4    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5    8:5    0   1.8T  0 part  
  └─md3   9:3    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0     4G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0     4G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdb2    8:18   0   512M  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sdb3    8:19   0     4G  0 part  
│ └─md2   9:2    0     4G  0 raid1 /tmp
├─sdb4    8:20   0     1K  0 part  
└─sdb5    8:21   0   1.8T  0 part  
  └─md3   9:3    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /
```

I don't undestand why i've 2 /boot and 2 /swap ? Ubunt is installed in my primary disk (but what ?)

How i can know if my 2HDD is mounted ?

Thank you for your help community !

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both disks are RAID bound, so they may in fact both be `/boot` partition.
RAID combines two disks into one (either for safety or for performance when only two disks are combined). Your is RAID 1 so it's built for safety

Comment: Hi @janmy ! When i'm logged with ssh, i've this information : `Usage of /:   0.1% of 1.78TB`, so, are you sur RAID combines my two disks ?

Comment: yes, the `lsblk` says:

    │ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot

which means this is raid 1.
`md` name comes from "multiple device" and is managed through `mdadm` program